# Non English letters was not copied properly using BCP copy

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I'm trying to copy csv to database table using bcp command. It's successfully copied, but the problem is non-English letters was migrated as some junk characters.

BCP query:

```
bcp "[table_name]" in "[file_path]" -F 1 -a 32768 -c -C RAW -t"|~|" -r "|\n|" -S "[server]" -U "[username]" -P "[password]" -d [database]
```

after migration

[image]

This is the source

[image]

Another Scenario:

When I use -C 65001 instead of -C RAW above issue is fixed. But I've fixed another bug that is opened again. Please help me on the same.

Source: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0exOH.png)
AfterMigration: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KiRj.png)

Comment: Please show the schema of the table. What format is the file encoded as? If it's UTF-8 then you need `-C 65001` not `-C RAW`. A proper format file might be wiser.

Comment: thanks @Charlieface already used -C 65001 again I used its working fine.
But why I've changed -C 65001 into -C RAW, I've already faced some other issue. Could u pls help me on this.

Comment: I found the issue. When the data type is text in sql its working with -C RAW and data type is nvarchar(max) its working with -C 65001

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem.
Previously I've used text and nvarchar data types in my destination tables.
using **-C 65001** the non English letters migrated properly for **nvarchar** columns not for text datatype.
using **-C RAW** the non English letters migrated properly for **text** columns not for nvarchar datatype.